# KD-Tree Implementation in SQL

Tags: python, sql, database, data-mining, kdtree

Is anyone aware of a [KD-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree), or similar spatial index, implemented in SQL? I was considering writing my own using Python and Django's ORM, but I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

I have a table containing millions of rows, with each row containing 128 columns representing image feature data. Given an arbitrary 128-element long list of image features, I want to use a KD-Tree to find the N most similar images in the database. I've found a lot of KD-Tree implementations, but they all appear to only load in local memory and don't scale or talk to databases.

Comment: what solution did you end up using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KD-tree does not work well for high-dimensional data, and 128 dimensions would be quite high. The KD-tree indexes each dimension at a different level of the tree, and when performing a query the algorithm will do a lot of back-tracking (searching both sides of a branch) and ends up searching most of the points in the tree. When this happens the advantages of using a tree structure disappear and an exhaustive comparison ends up running faster.

You may want to find an existing image similarity search system that you can map your data into. [Here is one called Lire](http://www.semanticmetadata.net/lire/) which extracts features from images and indexes them using Lucene.

If your work is more research-oriented you may want to read up on metric space indexes and approximate k-nearest neighbor search.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little out here, but your best bet may be using the Gist / Gin indexes inside of Postgresql

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. According to the docs, those index types are for full text search. I don't see how they would apply to a K-nearest neighbours problem.

Comment: GIN indexes are Gist indexes are intended to be a form of general index framework, one person has put a kd-tree on them (http://www.cs.purdue.edu/spgist/papers/icde06.pdf).